# How can I send a message every day at a specific hour?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot writing messages at specific times. Example:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Online!");
});
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getUTCHours();
var minute = now.getUTCMinutes();
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (hour === 10 && minute === 30) {
    client.channels.get("ChannelID").send("Hello World!");
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, it only works once I trigger another command like:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!ping")) {
  message.channel.send("pong!");
}
```

```
my message: !ping (at 10:10 o'clock)
-> pong!
-> Hello World!
```

I guess it needs something that constantly checks the time variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron): with this package you can set functions to be executed if the date matches the given pattern.
When building the pattern, you can use `*` to indicate that it can be executed with any value of that parameter and ranges to indicate only specific values: `1-3, 7` indicates that you accept `1, 2, 3, 7`.

These are the possible ranges:

- Seconds: `0-59`
- Minutes: `0-59`
- Hours: `0-23`
- Day of Month: `1-31`
- Months: `0-11` (Jan-Dec)
- Day of Week: `0-6` (Sun-Sat)

Here's an example:

```
var cron = require("cron");

function test() {
  console.log("Action executed.");
}

let job1 = new cron.CronJob('01 05 01,13 * * *', test); // fires every day, at 01:05:01 and 13:05:01
let job2 = new cron.CronJob('00 00 08-16 * * 1-5', test); // fires from Monday to Friday, every hour from 8 am to 16

// To make a job start, use job.start()
job1.start();
// If you want to pause your job, use job.stop()
job1.stop();
```

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
const cron = require('cron');

client.on('message', ...); // You don't need to add anything to the message event listener

let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 30 10 * * *', () => {
  // This runs every day at 10:30:00, you can do anything you want
  let channel = yourGuild.channels.get('id');
  channel.send('You message');
});

// When you want to start it, use:
scheduledMessage.start()
// You could also make a command to pause and resume the job
```

Answer (score 4):

As Federico stated, that is the right way to solve this problem but the syntax has changed and now with the new update of discord.js (v12) it would be like:

```
    // Getting Discord.js and Cron
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const cron = require('cron');
            
    // Creating a discord client
    const client = new Discord.Client();
        
    // We need to run it just one time and when the client is ready
    // Because then it will get undefined if the client isn't ready
    client.once("ready", () => {
      console.log(`Online as ${client.user.tag}`);
        
      let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 30 10 * * *', () => {
      // This runs every day at 10:30:00, you can do anything you want
      // Specifing your guild (server) and your channel
         const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('id');
         const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('id');
         channel.send('You message');
        });
            
        // When you want to start it, use:
        scheduledMessage.start()
    };

// You could also make a command to pause and resume the job
```

But still credits to Federico, he saved my life!

Comment: This might be better as a suggested edit of the accepted answer.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Nothing's happening. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490149/sending-message-to-a-specific-channel-at-a-specific-time-using-cron-in-discord

Comment: @Said Neder if i want to send a message every day at 8:00 pm what will be the code?