# Discord Daily greeting

Tags: javascript, discord

I am struggling to find any tutorial or help on this issue. I simply want the bot to send a message in a channel saying "Today is {day of the week}" every day. Anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get the day of the week

```js
const now = new Date();
const weekdays = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
];
const day = weekdays[now.getDay()];
console.log(day);
```

### Send it every day

[This very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53822507/13230118) seems to answer your question.
Applied to your problem:

```
const cron = require("cron");

function getDay() {
  return [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ][new Date().getDay()];
}

function greeting() { // To be fired
  const channel = your_channel;
  return channel.send(`Today is ${getDay()}!`);
}

const dailyGreeting = new cron.CronJob("00 00 08 * * *", greeting); // Fires every day at 08:00:00 AM
dailyGreeting.start(); // Start the job
```