# Sending message to a specific channel at a specific time using cron in Discord

Tags: javascript, cron, discord, discord.js

I want to send a message to a specific channel at 2:00 AM in Discord. I can't get it to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const cron = require("cron")
const client = new Discord.Client()
let channel = "ID#"

let job = new cron.CronJob('0 00 2 * * *', () => {
client.channels.cache.get(channel).send("Hello!!")
})

job.start()

client.login("Server#")
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you post them here as well

Comment: There's no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay now. Apparently, there's just 5 values in cron time string, and I put 6

Here's the code now:

```
let job = new cron.CronJob('00 2 * * *', () => {
client.channels.cache.get(channel).send("Hello!!")
})
```